# I typed python -v in my terminal and something weird happened

Tags: python, terminal

Thinking I was about to check the version of Python installed on my computer, I typed

```
python -v
```

in my terminal and I got a first line saying

> "installing zipimport hook", but then also a whole bunch of text (probably 50 or so lines of text), among which "import errno # builtin", "import posix # builtin", "import _codecs # builtin", and toward the end "Python 2.7.8 |Anaconda 2.1.0 (x86_64)| (default, Aug 21 2014, 15:21:46)"

What did I do? And what did that command install?

**EDIT**: the `v` I typed in `python -v` was a lowercase `v`. When I now try an uppercase `V`, I do get the version of Python on my computer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `python -V` (uppercase) or `python --version`. The lowercase `-v` means “verbose” and adds a bunch of diagnostic information to the output that you can safely ignore.

Comment: I see, thank you. Just to make sure, the lowercase version of "-v" is the same as the uppercase one except with added diagnostic information? In other words, it doesn't actually install anything on your computer?

Comment: @jeremyradcliff: It’s not the same as the uppercase one, but it's not installing anything in that sense, no.